# reading COM port value and printing in textArea which located inside the panel in java

Tags: java

I have to read a COM port and the data should be displayed inside the TextArea dynamically (data will come every minute), which I have created inside JPanel.

Comment: Have you at least taken a stab at it, or do you plan on someone completely writing your code for you?

Answer (score 1):

Some leads:

- [java2s has some examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/COM-Port.htm).
- this [**CommPortOpen class**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/OpenaserialportusingJavaCommunications.htm) can give you a good start.

Answer (score 1):

For reading from the serial port, have a look at the javacomm API here: http://java.sun.com/products/javacomm/

The User's Guide has more information and some example code: http://java.sun.com/products/javacomm/reference/docs/API_users_guide_3.html

Answer (score 0):

For a multi-platform application, look into [rxtx](http://www.rxtx.org/).

`javax.comm` has not had active development for a number of years.   The [rxtx](http://www.rxtx.org/) project has a compatible api as well as a more feature rich `gnu` package API.

There are examples with the source code and in the Wiki.