# problem reading serialport java

Tags: java, serial-communication

I'm reading data from a serial port in Java, but I'm not getting the full data, it is splitting ten it will comes.

Example:

If target device writes `datas_ok`, then I get `datas_` at first read then `ok` the second time.

```
case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:

                try {
                    while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                        numBytes = inputStream.available();
                        readBufferArray = new byte[numBytes];
                        // int readtheBytes = (int) inputStream.skip(2);
                        int readBytes = inputStream.read(readBufferArray);

                        one = new String(readBufferArray);
                        System.out.println("readBytes " + one);

                        handleFlashResponse(one);

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Hmm. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348777/reading-com-port-value-and-printing-in-textarea-which-located-inside-the-panel-in I detect a homework assignment..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read / convert an InputStream into a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/how-do-i-read-convert-an-inputstream-into-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

From the decription, it sounds like you're reading faster than the data is being sent.  This is normal.  If you read from the port and there's nothing there, then you need to keep trying (unless there's a call you can make for a blocking read).