# CRC calculation in Java

Tags: java, serial-port, crc, xmodem

I'm reading a file from serialport using x-modem protocol and 133 bytes packet.  I'm reading
in that

```
      1 byte is SOH
      2 byte packet number
      3 byte nagative of packet number
next  128 bytes data
      2 bytes CRC sent from other side.
```

I have to calculate CRC of 128 bytes data and 2 bytes crc sent from other side that I have to make it single byte and have to comapare with my calculated crc.  How can I do this in java?

Comment: Ok, what course is setting assignments about reading serial ports in Java? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348777/reading-com-port-value-and-printing-in-textarea-which-located-inside-the-panel-in

Answer (score 5):

Try using [Jacksum](https://jacksum.dev.java.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Sun JDK 1.6 contains sun.misc.CRC16, but there is a possibility this is not the CRC16 you're looking for, since there's several different polynomials in use.

Comment: The Sun class uses init=0, polynomial=0x1021. It also uses the naive bitwise implementation, not the table-driven implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my C code, which is trivial to port to Java - you are free to use it in any way you like.  The references to word are for a 16 bit unsigned value - you should be able to use a char instead in Java.

It's been too long since I worked with 16 bit CRC's so I don't recall if there are variations based on seeding.  I am pretty sure I used this code in a C implementation of X-Modem way back when.

The source is posted on [tech.dolhub.com](http://tech.dolhub.com/Code/CRC16).