# CRC-16-ANSI library for for Java/Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, crc

I need to compute the CRC-16 for arbitrary strings in a mixed java/groovy application.  Specifically, I need the CRC-16-ANSI aka CRC-16-IBM variant (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check for details; this is the modbus / USB version.)

I could implement my own, but I'd much rather find a library out there that someone has already tested to some degree.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732896/crc-calculation-in-java) question covers CRC 16 in Java vaguely, but since the application being discussed is Xmodem, the implementation is for CRC-16-CCITT, which isn't what I'm looking for.

I'm also vaguely aware of sun.misc.CRC16, but documentation for the library seems hard to come by since Oracle reorganized the Sun website, and I can't seem to find which CRC flavor it implements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a table driven version of the CRC16 polynomial used in MODBUS, etc. It was adapted from a C library:

```
import java.util.zip.Checksum;

public class CRC16 implements Checksum {

    private static final int[] TABLE= {
        0x0000, 0xc0c1, 0xc181, 0x0140, 0xc301, 0x03c0, 0x0280, 0xc241,
        0xc601, 0x06c0, 0x0780, 0xc741, 0x0500, 0xc5c1, 0xc481, 0x0440,
        0xcc01, 0x0cc0, 0x0d80, 0xcd41, 0x0f00, 0xcfc1, 0xce81, 0x0e40,
        0x0a00, 0xcac1, 0xcb81, 0x0b40, 0xc901, 0x09c0, 0x0880, 0xc841,
        0xd801, 0x18c0, 0x1980, 0xd941, 0x1b00, 0xdbc1, 0xda81, 0x1a40,
        0x1e00, 0xdec1, 0xdf81, 0x1f40, 0xdd01, 0x1dc0, 0x1c80, 0xdc41,
        0x1400, 0xd4c1, 0xd581, 0x1540, 0xd701, 0x17c0, 0x1680, 0xd641,
        0xd201, 0x12c0, 0x1380, 0xd341, 0x1100, 0xd1c1, 0xd081, 0x1040,
        0xf001, 0x30c0, 0x3180, 0xf141, 0x3300, 0xf3c1, 0xf281, 0x3240,
        0x3600, 0xf6c1, 0xf781, 0x3740, 0xf501, 0x35c0, 0x3480, 0xf441,
        0x3c00, 0xfcc1, 0xfd81, 0x3d40, 0xff01, 0x3fc0, 0x3e80, 0xfe41,
        0xfa01, 0x3ac0, 0x3b80, 0xfb41, 0x3900, 0xf9c1, 0xf881, 0x3840,
        0x2800, 0xe8c1, 0xe981, 0x2940, 0xeb01, 0x2bc0, 0x2a80, 0xea41,
        0xee01, 0x2ec0, 0x2f80, 0xef41, 0x2d00, 0xedc1, 0xec81, 0x2c40,
        0xe401, 0x24c0, 0x2580, 0xe541, 0x2700, 0xe7c1, 0xe681, 0x2640,
        0x2200, 0xe2c1, 0xe381, 0x2340, 0xe101, 0x21c0, 0x2080, 0xe041,
        0xa001, 0x60c0, 0x6180, 0xa141, 0x6300, 0xa3c1, 0xa281, 0x6240,
        0x6600, 0xa6c1, 0xa781, 0x6740, 0xa501, 0x65c0, 0x6480, 0xa441,
        0x6c00, 0xacc1, 0xad81, 0x6d40, 0xaf01, 0x6fc0, 0x6e80, 0xae41,
        0xaa01, 0x6ac0, 0x6b80, 0xab41, 0x6900, 0xa9c1, 0xa881, 0x6840,
        0x7800, 0xb8c1, 0xb981, 0x7940, 0xbb01, 0x7bc0, 0x7a80, 0xba41,
        0xbe01, 0x7ec0, 0x7f80, 0xbf41, 0x7d00, 0xbdc1, 0xbc81, 0x7c40,
        0xb401, 0x74c0, 0x7580, 0xb541, 0x7700, 0xb7c1, 0xb681, 0x7640,
        0x7200, 0xb2c1, 0xb381, 0x7340, 0xb101, 0x71c0, 0x7080, 0xb041,
        0x5000, 0x90c1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53c0, 0x5280, 0x9241,
        0x9601, 0x56c0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95c1, 0x9481, 0x5440,
        0x9c01, 0x5cc0, 0x5d80, 0x9d41, 0x5f00, 0x9fc1, 0x9e81, 0x5e40,
        0x5a00, 0x9ac1, 0x9b81, 0x5b40, 0x9901, 0x59c0, 0x5880, 0x9841,
        0x8801, 0x48c0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4b00, 0x8bc1, 0x8a81, 0x4a40,
        0x4e00, 0x8ec1, 0x8f81, 0x4f40, 0x8d01, 0x4dc0, 0x4c80, 0x8c41,
        0x4400, 0x84c1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47c0, 0x4680, 0x8641,
        0x8201, 0x42c0, 0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81c1, 0x8081, 0x4040
    };


    private int sum = 0xFFFF;

    public long getValue() {
        return sum;
    }

    public void reset() {
        sum = 0xFFFF;
    }

    public void update(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
        for (int i = off; i < off+len; i++)
            update((int)b[i]);
    }

    public void update(int b) {
        sum = (sum >> 8) ^ TABLE[( (sum)^(b&0xff) ) & 0xff];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CRC16 crc = new CRC16();
        crc.update(12);
        crc.update(16);
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString((int)crc.getValue()));
    }

}
```